# Why do you only need to show validity in one world when using trees in institutionist/constructivist logic?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, modal-logic, constructive-mathematics

Depicted below, my prof used a tree to prove that an argument is valid according to intuitionist logic.

However, I can't find a contradiction in world 0. Why is invalidity ascertained when all branches in one world (in this case w1) close?
[image]

Comment: Stop right there: you don't "show validity in one world" - - -

What you do show is that "the negation of the statement cannot be true in a world" or "given the premisses the negation of the conclusion cannot be true in a world" - - - 

I don't like this method of semantic tableaux (or proof trees, or many other names ), better learn to use natural deduction. - - -  Good luck.

Comment: Please, can you give us references for the version of the tableau method you are using ?

Comment: @Willemien, Thank you for clarifying. That was my understanding too, but I couldn't find any contradiction in w0. 
I prefer natural deduction too, but this is the method that they examine.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, my prof uses Graham Priest's text "An Introduction to Non-Classical Logics". The tableau's depicted in that text resemble the tableau depicted in this question.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA you are reading the symbols correctly, however there is no contradiction (as far as I can see) on p in w0. We know that ⇁p +0, and p -0, but I don't think that that is a contradiction. There is a contradiction about both p in w1 and q in w1 but nothing for p or q in w0.

Comment: You are right: I've modified my answer below. But, as you can see example page 109 (2nd ed) :  $\vdash_I p \supset \lnot \lnot p$. The tableau close with $p, -2$ and $p,+2$. It is not necessary that the contradiction is in $w_0$.

Comment: Stop again, you didn't proof that $ (\lnot p \lor q)  $ and  $ \lnot( P -> q) $ is a contradiction in world 1  you proved something completely different. - - 

what you proved is: - - 

 1 if in some world (0) $ (\lnot p \lor q)  $ and $ \lnot( P -> q) $ are true then 
 - - 
 2 there is a world (world 1) visuable from this world(0)  where $ (\lnot p \lor q) $ ,  $  \lnot( P -> q) $,  $ p $ and $ \lnot q $ are true - - 

 3 there is no world where $ (\lnot p v q) $ , $ p $and $-q all are  true - -

Comment: (backtracking ) - - 

4 world 1 cannot exist - -

 5 world 0 cannot exist - - 
 
 6 therefore $ (\lnot p v q)  $ and $ \lnot( P -> q) $ cannot both be true. - - 

 7 therefore $ (\lnot p v q) -> ( P -> q) $ is true. - - QED?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can easily prove that :

> $(\lnot p \lor q) \rightarrow (p \rightarrow q)$

holds *intuitionistically* with *Natural Deduction*.

---

I'm quite unfamiliar with the intuitionistical version of tableau method; I've seen :

- Melvin Fitting, [Intuitionistic logic Model theory and Forcing](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0720422566) (1969), page 28

where the usual tableau rules are modified as follows :

> > $$\frac{S, \ F(\lnot X)}{S_T, \ TX} \quad \text {(F $\lnot$)}$$

and :

> > $$\frac{S, \ F(X \rightarrow Y)}{S_T, \ TX, FY} \quad \text {(F $\rightarrow$)}$$

where $S_T$ means $\{TX \ | \ TX \in S \}$.

---

Thus :

$1) \ \{ T(\lnot p \lor q) , F(p \rightarrow q) \}$

then apply $(F \rightarrow)$ :

$2) \ \{ T(\lnot p \lor q) , Tp, Fq) \}$

then apply $(T \lor)$ to produce two branches :

$3_L) \ \{ T(\lnot p \lor q) , T\lnot p, Tp, Fq) \}$

and :

$3_R) \ \{ T(\lnot p \lor q) , Tq, Tp, Fq) \}$.

The right brach $3_R)$ closes by $\{ Tq, Fq) \}$; finally, we we have to apply $(T \lnot)$ to the left branch $3_L)$ producing :

$4) \ \{ T(\lnot p \lor q) , Fp, Tp, Fq) \}$;

now also this branch closes by $\{ Fp, Tp \}$, and the validity of the formula is proved.

---

---

*Here is the proof with* **Natural Deduction** :

*1)* $\lnot p \lor q$ --- assumed [a]

*2)* $p$ --- assumed [b]

*3)* $\lnot p$ --- assumed from 1) for $\lor$-elimination

*4)* $\bot$ --- from 2) and 3) by $\rightarrow$-elimination

*5)* $q$ --- from 4) by $\bot$-elimination

*6)* $q$ --- assumed from 1) for $\lor$-elimination

*7)* $q$ --- from 3)-5), 6) and 1) by $\lor$-elimination

*8)* $p \rightarrow q$ --- from 2) and 7) by $\rightarrow$-introduction, discharging [b]

> *9)* $(\lnot p \lor q) \rightarrow (p \rightarrow q)$ --- from 1) and 8) by $\rightarrow$-introduction, discharging [a].

---

---

*Comment*

The left-branch of your tree, we have a contradiction in $w_1$ on $p$, labelled both $+1$ and $−1$, and also in the right-branch we have a contradiction in $w_1$ on $q$, labelled both $−1$ and $+1$.

Having shown that the the tableau trying to falsify the formula $(¬p∨q)→(p→q)$ closes without success (i.e. all finished branches are "crossed") we have shown that it is not *falsifiable*.

Being not falsifiable, the formula is *valid*, i.e. true in all models.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your comment. 
When using tableaus with classical logic we negate the conclusion and if we cannot close all branches then the argument is invalid. In this case, we negated the conclusion, and cannot close all branches in w0. I expected that to mean the argument is invalid. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Hal - see my comment above : it is not necessary that we close them at $w_0$. Assume that the branch closing at $w_1$ means that - being **no** contradiction in $w_0$ - the formula is true in $w_0$. Then, by trasitivity, it is true also in $w_1$, contrary to the contradiction found there...